# How to isolate the plots of this method?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, data-visualization

I am using the [rugarch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/index.html) package and I fitted a model. Now I want to look at the output and use the plot function. My problem is, that the 5th plot contains some subplots, which are plotted in one device, but I want to plot each in a single device. How can I do this? As an example I give you a code example, which uses the sp500ret data of the package:

The code:

```
library(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)

somemodel<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(2, 2)), 
mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1), include.mean = TRUE), 
distribution.model = "ged")

somefit<-ugarchfit(spec=somemodel,data=sp500ret)

rollingesti = ugarchroll(somemodel, sp500ret, n.start=500,
 refit.every = 100, refit.window = 'moving', window.size = 500, 
  calculate.VaR = FALSE, keep.coef = TRUE)

plot(rollingesti,which=5)
```

the `plot(rollingesti,which=5)` plots several plots into one device, I want to isolate them.

[image: ro]

So I want to have them as single plots and bigger, now, they are too small, since they are all put into one output.

Comment: Running your code I get the following error (at somemodel<-): `ugarchspec-->error: the cond.distribution does not appear to be a valid choice.`. Perhaps it is the  version of r I am working with but to me the example is not reproducible...

Comment: Several errors in your code. distribution.model = "GED" should be distribution.model = "ged". And spmodel does not exist.

Comment: @thijsvandenbergh ok, sorry, I corrected the errors! Rugarch only works with R version >= 3.00. I also added the plot output.

Comment: I am still searching for an answer, so any hint would be great!

Comment: I have 2.15 version of R, but according to the vignette http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf. Try to use `plot(rollingesti,which=1:<numberOfPlots>)`

Comment: @storaged you mean e.g. plot(rollingesti,which=5:1) ? This does not work. I want to have the single plots of the 5th output as single plots, so I need plot(rollingesti,which=5). So plot(rollingesti,which=1:2) does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does not work (at least for me), i.e. it does not converge. However, this one works:

```
library(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)
spec <- ugarchspec(distribution.model = "std")
mod <- ugarchroll(spec, data = sp500ret[1:2000,], n.ahead = 1, 
                 n.start = 1000,  refit.every = 100, refit.window = "moving", 
                 solver = "hybrid", fit.control = list(),
                 calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05),
                 keep.coef = TRUE)
```

First, we find a method that is used in `plot(mod, which = 5)`. It can be obtained by

```
getMethod("plot", c(x = "uGARCHroll", y = "missing"))
```

You are interested in the following lines

```
.intergarchrollPlot(x, choices = choices, plotFUN = paste(".plot.garchroll", 
            1:5, sep = "."), which = which, VaR.alpha = VaR.alpha, 
            density.support = density.support, ...)
```

where `choices` is `"Fit Coefficients (with s.e. bands)"`. By inspecting `rugarch:::.intergarchrollPlot` we finally arrive to `rugarch:::.plot.garchroll.5`. These plots are not returned in any list or similar, hence I provide a bit modified version so that you could use them separately. Here I changed the first two and the last one line:

```
library(xts)
x <- mod
vmodel = x@model$spec@model$modeldesc$vmodel
if (!x@model$keep.coef) 
  stop("\n\nplot-->error: keep.coef set to FALSE in estimation\n")
coefs = x@model$coef
m = dim(coefs[[1]]$coef)[1]
N = length(coefs)
Z = matrix(NA, ncol = m, nrow = N)
Zup = matrix(NA, ncol = m, nrow = N)
Zdn = matrix(NA, ncol = m, nrow = N)
for (i in 1:m) {
  Z[, i] = sapply(coefs, FUN = function(y) y$coef[i, 1])
  Zup[, i] = Z[, i] + sapply(coefs, FUN = function(y) y$coef[i, 
                                                             2])
  Zdn[, i] = Z[, i] - sapply(coefs, FUN = function(y) y$coef[i, 
                                                             2])
}
dt = sapply(coefs, FUN = function(y) as.character(y$index))
cnames = rownames(coefs[[1]]$coef)
np = rugarch:::.divisortable(m) # added rugarch:::
```

This is a function for each plot separately, `i` is a number of the graph, e.g. from 1 to 7 in this case:

```
plotFun <- function(i){
  plot(xts(Z[, i], as.POSIXct(dt)), type = "l", 
       ylim = c(min(Zdn[, i]), max(Zup[, i])), ylab = "value", xlab = "", main = "", 
       minor.ticks = FALSE, ann = FALSE, auto.grid = FALSE)
  lines(xts(Zdn[, i], as.POSIXct(dt)), col = 2)
  lines(xts(Zup[, i], as.POSIXct(dt)), col = 2)
  title(cnames[i], line = 0.4, cex = 0.9)
  grid()
}
```

For example:

```
plotFun(1)
plotFun(2)
```

Comment: thanks, I need time to check your code and to understand it. I will come back and ask further questions or accept your answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have now checked the code and it works. Therefore I will accept your answer. But one last question: I know, that I can get the values used to create the plot via the command coef(mod). These are the estimates and their used sd. errors. But how can I get isolated values of these outputs? E.g. coef(mod)[1] gives me the estimates of omega and so for one certain window. Now, I want to extract e.g. the estimate of omega for this timepoint (this window). I want to do this for all elemets of coef(mod) to get the isolated values with the corresponding date,

Comment: so that I can recreate the plot by myself using plot(values,date) and so. How can I achieve this?

Comment: and one minor thing about the plot itself, how can I get a more detailed y-axis? So more detailed ticks on the y-axis?

Comment: @StatTistician, `coef(mod)` is a list of lists, so `coef(mod)[[1]]` returns the list of the first window. It has two elements: `index` and `coef`, so as I understand what you want is a matrix `coef(mod)[[1]]$coef` and particularly a column of estimates `coef(mod)[[1]]$coef[, 1]`. It seems that the answer to your question about ticks would not fit in the comment: it is a bit complicated since `plot.xts` itself draws `axis(1, ...` and `axis(2, ...`. However, it seems that maximal number of ticks is used (at least in my example), have you tried to zoom the plot? Then there appear some more labels

Comment: @StatTistician, if you are still interested in the number of ticks, I could try to edit my answer and to make a font size of the labels smaller, so that more of them could be seen.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I would be definitely interested in the ticks-problem, since I do not know how to implement this (I also do not know how to zoom the plot in R). However, I see, that this is already another question, so I will accept your answer and if you want, you can add this to your answer. Thanks a lot again!